# Why is python only outputting 6 numbers seperated by '...', when the expectation is output of 10,000 numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

The full problem:  **Generate a NumPy array of 10,000 random numbers (called x) and create a Variable storing the equation y=5x^2−3x+15**

```
import numpy as np 
data = np.random.randint(1000, size=10000)
x = tf.constant(data, name='x')
y = tf.Variable(5 * (x**2) - (3 * x) + 15)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print(session.run(y))
```

The output is [4528679 4547733  119675 ... 2215797    1247 1703543].
What is the reason for not including the full 10,000 random numbers within the array?  And what does the '...' signify?

Answer (score 2):

That's just numpy summarising your array, so you don't get 1000 numbers printed to the terminal.  You can control the threshold where this kicks in by using the `threshold` argument to `np.set_printoptions`:

```
threshold : int, optional
    Total number of array elements which trigger summarization
    rather than full repr (default 1000).
```

Demo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(100)
>>> np.set_printoptions(threshold=5)
>>> print(a)
[ 0  1  2 ... 97 98 99]
>>> np.set_printoptions(threshold=500)
>>> print(a)
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
 96 97 98 99]
```